# How to ask prospective employer to pay for relocation and first few months rent?

Tags: job-offer, relocation

A company offered me an entry level job and I will be relocating to a new place. I was wondering what the best way is to ask the company to pay for my relocation costs (e.g. moving company) and the first 3 months rent or at least the first month's rent? How do I ask the company for relocation costs (advanced rent, moving) without coming across as entitled and overbearing? Also is asking this question risky for someone who received a job offer?

I want to ask for an advance on expenses like rent and deposit for accomodation because I may not be able to afford them until after the first month of working.

Comment: What sort of distances are involved? Moving 10 miles across town may be different from moving to a new country or continent.

Comment: Depending on country of course, relocation reimbursement is usually put into the "perks" or compensation for a prospective job. If a company doesn't have it listed on their site/the job app, it may be safe to assume that you won't get anything for that, especially with an entry level position.

Comment: "I want to ask for an advance on expenses like rent and deposit" - this is a little different to asking for relocation expenses, and an advance on salary is often something a company will offer to new hires.

Comment: Seems like you want a lot for an entry level job. Are they aware you will need to relocate?

Comment: Will being denied relocation expenses mean you have to reject the job offer?

Comment: @Laconic Droid international relocation

Comment: Theses are things I would expect to be covered during the negotiation phase. If you've already accepted the offer, I wouldn't expect there to be much recourse at this point.

Comment: @Joel Etherton I have not accepted the offer.

Comment: @Sa2 - In which case, whether or not they ultimately pay relocation, I don't think it's unreasonable or "risky" to ask if the offer any assistance for an international move.

Comment: @Sa2: Then I would ask it in a way that asks for the availability for assistance in performing the relocation. Many companies are understanding in these areas and will be willing to perform some form of advance with a re-payment schedule. Many companies won't, so a "hard line" might cause them to retract an offer.

Comment: @Laconic Droid an advance on salary would be better than a relocation expenses reimbursement.

Comment: @Fattie It depends on the industry. In high tech I've seen plenty of companies offer relation for entry level jobs.

Comment: @Sa2, Would you please state which country it is ? and which industry it is ? In the US, most companies would provide pay for relocation. Some very small companies don't pay for relocation as they want to cut cost. Most US companies won't pay for 1 or 3 month rents because your salary should be able to cover your cost of living. You can ask your Human Resources for more info.

Comment: Before accepting any relocation benefit - check the tax laws of the destination country and understand them. In many countries, such a benefit is taxable like it's salary, even if the company pays for flights, hotels, movers, etc, directly.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 I've had relocation offers include 1 month rent.  The idea being that they need to put you somewhere while you apartment search.  More than that would be unusual.  But 1 month is normally part of relocation packages.

Comment: @Fattie: I was hired on an entry-level helpdesk call center job, located on a different continent altogether. The company paid for my flights, provided a B&B for the first month and up to half a day PTO every week to find housing (and/or a car), and comped me a flat fee for rent the next two months. Nothing the OP has posted, nor wondered if it would be provided, is unusual. Your response is disproportionately dramatic for a posted question that is not.

Comment: @Joel Etherton The company say that they offer a relocation package which includes help with finding an apartment, and reimbursement for costs such as flight, luggage etc. There is no mention of relocation support for housing costs (i.e. rent and deposit). So is it okay to ask them if they can loan me the costs for the first month's rent?

Comment: @Sa2, Keep in mind that in some countries, they may require a deposit of 1 to 3 months rent before they even allow you to move in. In Japan, it can be as much as 10 months rent just for the deposit alone. As a foreigner, chances are that you won't have any credit history that they can easily verify. So do some research on the kind of deposit that you may be required to pay. For instance, you may even need deposits for utilities as well.

Answer (score 10):

The likelihood of getting relocation depends very much on the industry. High-tech firms will often pay fresh graduates full relocation. Other industries where the demand is lower? Less likely but still possible.

It won't hurt to ask. Only the most sensitive (or frankly insane) companies will give you a black mark for asking.

How to ask?

Just like you ask anything else:

- Ask
- Stay polite
- Don't make it seem like a demand
- Explain why you need it ("I'm starting in my career and I don't have any savings")
- Don't get upset or try to argue if they say no.

If they do say no, then ask if they can loan you the costs ("advance on salary")

**What might be covered.**

Relocation packages vary, but the norm is either a) a fixed amount towards moving or b) covering extra expenses that you wouldn't have spent if you hadn't moved (up to a limit). First month's rent isn't usual to cover, because you would have had to pay for a month's rent if you hadn't moved, so it isn't an extra expense. Some places might pay for a hotel for a short time while you look for accommodation.

Comment: Why explain? Who cares?

Comment: Because it makes it clear that you are not asking just "to get more money" but because you have a real problem. This makes them understand you are not just trying to milk the company for any money you can get. Also it increases the empathy the person you are asking is likely to have, which makes it more likely that they will agree. Which is your goal.

Comment: The likelihood the company will agree is a function of A) how much the hiring manager wants to hire you and B) how much room is left in the scale for the position. It's _possible_ the hiring manager would care about a sob story, but it's very unlikely to make a whit of difference to HR/payroll/whoever has budgeted to hire into the position. In my personal experience I'd find something like "I'm just starting my career and I don't have any savings" to sound pretty unprofessional, though not likely enough to make much difference either way.

Comment: My main point is that I don't see that saying this type of thing will _add_ anything. Negotiation around compensation is so utterly unremarkable that justifying it would strike me as awkward and strange.

Comment: It's not about a sob story. If you just say "can I have payment for relocation expenses" the manager may think you just want more money, and will ask for anything you can get. If you say "I've got student debts, no savings and I need to spend thousands of dollars to move myself, can the company help me" they are less likely to think that. It's called the human factor.

Comment: I guess we just disagree, then. You seem to think there's some grasping, negative connotation to negotiation. I don't. The company wants to hire you - they've made an offer. You're deciding whether or not to accept. This is 100% routine. If they were offering too little compensation, you'd need more in order to accept. There is nothing wrong with wanting more money. If you didn't want money, they wouldn't have offered any!

Comment: I like your answer but explaining about having no savings doesn't seem right even though it is a valid reason. The issue with that is that I don't want to come across as needy or a charity case.

Comment: Employers understand that many people just graduated and starting out in the profession often don't have savings. Saying why you need the money makes it clear that you are asking for a reason, and thus you won't be just asking for money at every opportunity you get (meaning you will be less 'needy'). If expenses are discretionary, then giving them a reason makes it more likely that they will give it to you.

Comment: Also the other answer on June 14th 17:18 says that they shouldn't rescind the offer unless I state my request as mandatory. Isn't there a chance that if I say I need relocation assistance because I don't have savings, they will assume I cannot afford to move to start the job which could cause them to withdraw the offer?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That makes sense. However I am not just graduating. However this will be my first real job in that field, I only have a single internship experience.

Comment: They won't assume that unless you say so. So don't say things like "I can't relocate unless you give me money" (that would be a 'demand') and if they so no you say "OK, I'll find a way to pay for it." The difference between "just graduating" and "first job" isn't important.

Comment: I see. I'll say "Does the company offer relocation assistance in any form?", and then add on that "I'm starting in my career and I don't have any savings". Fingers crossed :)

Comment: I was wondering, if they say no should I then ask if they can loan me the costs i.e. an advance on salary, or say okay, I'll find a way to pay for it? By going with the former, would I appear too pushy?

Comment: Okay, I used your answer, and there were no reprecautions. The company say that they offer a relocation package which includes help with finding an apartment, and reimbursement for costs such as flight, luggage etc. There is no mention of relocation support for housing costs. So is it okay to ask them if they can loan me the costs for the first month's rent?

Comment: I've added to the answer to say what is normally covered.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. Is the company likely to withdraw the offer if I ask something like: "I am very grateful for the opportunity and the help, and since I need to pay a deposit and rent, I was wondering if your company can loan me the cost for the first month's rent?"? Alternatively I could ask for the first month's rent indirectly by saying "What is your policy regarding an advance on salary for new hires?". Is the alternative better?

Answer (score 4):

It entirely depends on the company whether they will or not.  When I started right out of school in an entry level job with a large corporation, they provided relocation assistance - their headquarters was not in a top city, and they knew they were hiring right out of college so recruits didn't have deep pockets.

Ask whatever HR person you've been put into contact with if the company offers relocation assistance in any form. They may say "no" but it shouldn't drive the offer away unless you state it as mandatory.

Comment: So what is the best way to word this question for the HR person so that they don't rescind the offer?

Comment: “Does the company offer relocation assistance in any form?”  Not rocket science.

Comment: The company say that they offer a relocation package which includes help with finding an apartment, and reimbursement for costs such as flight, luggage etc. There is no mention of relocation support for housing costs. So is it okay to ask them if they can loan me the costs for the first month's rent?

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's best not to create any drama for an entry level job and handle anything like that yourself. Most places have a backpackers or other cheap accommodation to get you through until payday.

Nothing to stop you asking, but be prepared for them to lose interest in pursuing their offer.

Comment: This is a good answer. Yes, I can see how they would interpret such a request as a prospective employee creating drama even before they have joined.

Comment: They have made the offer. Any company who rescinds an offer *just for asking the question* is a) rare and b) not worth working for. It's not "drama" to ask, as long as you stay polite and accept that whatever answer they give is the answer.

Comment: @DJClayworth they didn't offer to relocate the OP, changes the whole ball game internationally. Perhaps not your locale, but huge logistics involved in some places so that discussion takes place before an offer is made. Here would be automatically ghosted if you wanted 3 months rent in advance for an entry level position.

Comment: @DJClayworth what is the most polite and professional way to ask so that they don't rescind the offer?

Comment: @Kilisi Depends on field, making this a bad answer.  Every single one of my classmates got offers that included relocation when we left college. And none of them put anyone up in a hostel.  These days they wouldn't remotely risk it-  too big a chance a laptop with company info gets stolen.  Ask, but look up what typical relocation packages in your field are first.

Comment: @GabeSechan that would be locale specific then, because I've never seen it happen in several countries. The only time they will relocate is when it's clearly an option from the start. Lots of people are relocated here, but it's specifically part of the application process.

Comment: @Kilisi It probably is locale specific.  In the US its extremely common for professional positions, especially for technical roles.  The US is a big place, and the colleges aren't generally near employment hubs (although some are).

Comment: @GabeSechan it's common for international entry level? OP is relocating from another country. Within USA makes sense, seems strange from overseas though, but feel free to downvote.

Comment: @Kilisi If they want you enough to pay to get you an H1-B visa, they're definitely giving you a relocation package.  They'll spend more than that on lawyer fees.

Comment: @GabeSechan I know the process, and usually entry level isn't worth the headache and when it is, it's clearly specified about relocation. There's no mention of the US in the question or anything else you're talking about, you should make your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

**NB**: I'm answering the question as asked, without assumption.

In a negotiation situation - as in, you have an offer in hand, but have not accepted it yet - the way to ask a prospective employer for *x* is as follows: "Of course, I'm evaluating my options. What would make your offer an easy 'yes' for me would be if you were to include *x*."

It is easy. Practice in front of a mirror, or on the phone with a friend, if you think it would help you. Say it plainly and easily. It's entirely natural and expected to negotiate.